# Async Requests .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I'm having to use .NET 3.5 for a client project. Usually I'd use .NET 4.5 and use Async/Await, but I can't use 4.5 for this project.

I'm not sure if my solution is correct, but it appears simple. Basically the following method will download a file asynchronously, and return a boolean to indicate success or not. But in the main code, I'm not sure how to actually wait for the response from the method before proceeding to the next line of code.

```
private bool DownloadJSONFile(string url)
    {
        bool responseStatus = false;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.BeginGetResponse(result => {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result))
            {
                if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    responseStatus = true;
                }
            }
        }, null);

        return responseStatus;
    }
```

Here is the main function calling `DownloadJSONFile`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        bool a = DownloadJSONFile("http://myserver.com/clients.json");
        MessageBox.Show("Download complete");
}
```

At the moment the message box is displaying before the request is complete. Which I understand is completely normal.

How is it possible to wait for `DownloadJSONFile` to complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have it call another method when it's done

```
request.BeginGetResponse(result => {
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result))
    {
        if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            responseStatus = true;
            DoSomething();

        }
    }
}, null);
```

Then add this somewhere

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}
```

Otherwise, you could look into .Net 3.5 AsyncBridge: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncBridge.Net35

Comment: The problem I have with it calling other methods is that as the code begins to grow it'll end up in one long chain of methods calling each other when one completes. I will take a look at Async Bridge. Thanks.

Comment: The only other way I could think of that's somewhat practical is to create a class that fires an event when it's done. Then, you can add event handlers at the appropriate time.