# Async API call in dot net 3.5 client profile

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am currently making multiple Sync API calls however this seems to be a bottleneck. I am unable to use async / await as the target framework is 3.5 client profile.

Is there a way to invoke api asynchronously in 3.5 client profile?

I tried using the AsyncBridge however wasn't able to go beyond installing the nuget. any code snippet to invoke api call using asyncbridge would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async Requests .NET 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760308/async-requests-net-3-5)

Comment: I am unable to integrate AsyncBridge as pointed out in the solution. I am trying to look up implementation of asyncbridge within a 3.5 client profile

Answer (score 0):

If you have constraint's in upgrading the framework, you can use multiple techniques which supports async  operations (like methods ending with Begin *). Or you can wrap your sync calls in this way as stated in

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.80).aspx